# I can't do auto-implement interfaces C#-Visual studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, interface, omnisharp

I can't implement interfaces in VsCode. Everything works well but interfaces. I've tried reinstalling vs code and downgrading C#(Omnisharp). There is no option about implementing interface and there is no implement message just like the image. Thanks for your helpings for now.

[image: interface]

Edit: I realized now Implementation wotks in the Projects have *.sln files.

Comment: Restart VS Code and see if it does. Sometimes you need to restart it in to make the extentions work.

Comment: I realized it can work which have *.sln file projects(Created in Visual Studio). But restart is not working in any time.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. I had .NET 5 sdk automatically. I uninstalled .Net5 and used netcoreapp3.1 version. And Problem solved.